# Netty 4 MessageToByteEncoder with FileRegion

Tags: netty

I am migrating from raw NIO to netty.  The response I need to send back is as follows

```
short
long
long
long
file
```

I have the following working example, and was wondering how to move the FileRegion into the encoder.

MessageToByteEncoder

```
@Override
protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final BlockResponse msg,
    final ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
  out.writeShort(DataServerMessage.DATA_SERVER_RESPONSE_MESSAGE);
  out.writeLong(msg.getBlockId());
  out.writeLong(msg.getOffset());
  out.writeLong(msg.getLength());
}
```

ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter

```
    ctx.write(new BlockResponse(blockId, offset, readLength));
    FileChannel channel = closer.register(file.getChannel());
    ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFileRegion(channel, offset, readLength));
    future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

I think that if i did writeAndFlush in the adapter to the response (and put the file in there), then I could do another writeAndFlush in the encoder, but then the encoder would need to close it.  Is there another way?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the updated code that works:

```
public static final class Encoder extends MessageToMessageEncoder<BlockResponse> {
  private static final int HEADER_LENGTH = 2 + 4 * 3; // short, 3 longs

  @Override
  protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final BlockResponse msg,
      final List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    out.add(createHeader(ctx, msg));
    if (msg.getChannel() != null) {
      out.add(new DefaultFileRegion(msg.getChannel(), msg.getOffset(), msg.getLength()));
    }
  }

  private ByteBuf createHeader(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final BlockResponse msg) {
    ByteBuf header = ctx.alloc().buffer(HEADER_LENGTH);
    header.writeShort(DataServerMessage.DATA_SERVER_RESPONSE_MESSAGE);
    header.writeLong(msg.getBlockId());
    header.writeLong(msg.getOffset());
    header.writeLong(msg.getLength());
    return header;
  }
}
```

ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter

```
ChannelFuture future =
    ctx.writeAndFlush(new BlockResponse(blockId, offset, readLength, channel));
future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
future.addListener(new ClosableResourceChannelListener(file));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to also trigger a FileRegion from within an encoder you need to use a MessageToMessageEncoder and allocate the ByteBuf by your own inside there.

Comment: So the header i allocate my self (from ctx) and send it out as out.add(header), then I say out.add(fileRegion)?  Ill try this out, thanks!